# What does it take to _guarantee_ that child processes are killed before parent exits in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I do a fair bit of work on streaming real time data and I've found that a process model for isolating different bits of my system from each other works very well.  It's often very convenient/terse to be able to popen a child process and read data from it in a streaming fashion for the life of a program.  However, if a child process isn't properly wait()-ed on before the parent ends, you can pretty easily end up with zombies or orphans.

What I'm looking for is basically what it would take to get RAII-style guarantees on child processes being properly cleaned up.  Ideally without regard to *how* the parent exits, be it in response to a signal, calling exit(), throwing an exception, whatever.  I'd like to sleep easy knowing I can't ever generate a zombie or orphaned process.

Comment: Well you can't, because of `kill -9`, but in general you need to ensure all foked children are `wait()`-ed for. This is not feasible via all exit paths, e.g. signal handlers.

Comment: If the parent has exited what is the concern with regards to zombie processes? They will be adopted by and waited for by `init`. Orphans on the other hand are another matter. So to clarify, are you really concerned about zombies after the parent dies and if so why?

Comment: Well I'm a firm believer in cleaning up after myself, so if I can avoid zombies all the better, but I definitely have to not leave any orphans.

Comment: Dunno if this is applicable in your case, but I have my child processes select() on stdin (amongst other descriptors), so that when their stdin handle gets closed they will notice it, and respond by exiting ASAP.  That way if/when the parent process goes away (for any reason), the child processes will go away also.

Comment: @Jeremy, interesting, I have my programs check ctrl-C so they can cleanup nicely, your idea might help me on the other side where I didn't get a signal to the process group...

Comment: I should mention, in an ideal world, this technique would work any child process, even those not modified to specifically work it it.

Comment: You can arrange to send a signal to all the processes in a process group, so if your parent process forms its own process group, the children will be in it and the parent can send `SIGTERM`, for instance, to the children before exiting.  You're still vulnerable to the parent being killed unilaterally — e.g. by a `SIGKILL` signal.  Your children should die when they write to a pipe that no longer has a reader — assuming you've done your plumbing correctly in the children.  If you end up with orphans, it's likely you didn't close enough pipes so the system doesn't know the kids should die.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, when you know the child `pid`, probably as the returned value from a call to `fork()`  the code can wait for the child to die via:

```
waitpid( pid, &status, 0);
```

which could be followed by the appropriate macro invocations to extract the returned status from the child, if the parent process is actually interested in that status.

Note: not waiting for the child process to die can result in creating `zombie` processes.  Which usually take a re-boot to eliminate

Comment: Sure, but that won't work for any kind of abnormal termination of the parent.